# Kafka S3 connect: timed rotation based on wall clock doesn't seem to write

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

We are using Confluent's Kafka [S3 Connector](https://docs.confluent.io/5.2.0/connect/kafka-connect-s3/index.html), version 5.2.1.  Running with one node in a Distributed Worker setting.

Per [documentation](https://docs.confluent.io/5.2.0/connect/kafka-connect-s3/configuration_options.html#connector) we should be able to set the flush to S3 both on a size as well as time based interval.

We are using the following flush settings

```
{ 
  "rotate.interval.ms": 300000, // 5 minutes
  "flush.size": 1000,
  "timestamp.extractor": "Wallclock" // default
  ... (other settings)
}
```

but I don't see any data being written in a topic that has less than 1000 messages but has data available.

However, when I change the setting to a smaller flush size and remove the rotate interval:

```
{ 
  "flush.size": 5, // some small amount
  "timestamp.extractor": "Wallclock", // default
  ... (other settings)
}
```

With all other settings the same, I can see data in the s3 bucket immediately.

I am not changing any other settings so I am pretty confident that there is connectivity to s3 and I see the task workers being deployed.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want every 5 minutes, you should prefer `rotate.schedule.interval.ms`, which forces Connect to dump files in this interval.

> This configuration ensures that file commits are invoked every configured interval. ... The commit will be performed at the scheduled time, regardless of the previous commit time or number of messages

`rotate.interval.ms` will inspect the record timestamps against the first consumed record in a batch.

> the time interval is determined by using a timestamp extractor

If you have less records than the flush size, then the full batch will just wait in memory until new records come in with a timestamp difference greater than the first seen record.

`flush.size` always takes priority over all other time settings, when writing files last time I looked at the source code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 

To make sure I understood `rotate.interval.ms`: If we have a topic that has N < `flush.size` records, and it's inactive (no new records), we may not ever flush with just the `rotate.interval.ms` defined because there wouldn't be new records to determine the timestamp difference necessary for the rotation?

Comment: That is my understanding of the properties, yes.